# manually able to log in but with salenium webdriver its showing invalid credentials,how to handle this?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, browser-automation

i am using Selenium webdriver with java to automate an angularJS based app. Manually i am able to log in to the application but in automation its showing invalid credentials. I checked with credential, they are same. I tried two location strategies Css selector and Xpath  results are same.

> /*driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#username")).sendKeys("9813555555");//username
>
> ```
>     driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#password")).sendKeys("9813555555");//password
>       driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-primary.login-btn")).click();//login
> */    
>
>       driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/input")).sendKeys("98135555555");
>
>       driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div/input")).sendKeys("98135555555");
>
>       driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();
> ```

Comment: Which browser are you using to run the test? Can you run Charles web proxy or something and capture the request? See if the username/password are set correctly in the request.

Comment: i am using firefox i dont idea about charles proxy .can you help me with that

Comment: https://www.charlesproxy.com/ Install this and start listening to all http traffic and see if your request contains the proper credentials before sent to backend

Comment: at this pc i dont have admin privileges can u suggest me something else @srijith

Comment: Are you sure that automated test is pointing to the same server that you are manually logging into?  We have multiple test environments and sometimes noobs get confused about which server they're pointing at.

Comment: yes i am sure its pointing same server ,both are in same test environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Css selector was duplicating and it was sending credential to admin instead of  normal user  .it was difficult to find as login ur at credential input was same.handled by editing xpath.