# Website not accepting login credentials via selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to login to abc.com via selenium. It always shows

```
Invalid Details. Please check the EmailID-Password combination.
```

Below is my code :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def page_is_loaded(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://login.abc.com/nLogin/Login.php?msg=0&URL=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.abc.com")
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(page_is_loaded)

email_field = driver.find_element_by_id("emailTxt")
email_field.send_keys("enter email")
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id("pwd1")
password_field.send_keys("enter password")
password_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I was able to login to facebook via selenium, but I am getting this problem.

I have reffered to :- [manually able to log in but with salenium webdriver its showing invalid credentials,how to handle this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241487/manually-able-to-log-in-but-with-salenium-webdriver-its-showing-invalid-credenti) but the answer did not make sense.

Comment: I didn't face any problem using the code with chrome. Can you check again?

Comment: it is working in chrome, not frirefox